# Using prefix decrement operator (--): variable is 0 but not 0?

Tags: c, operators, decrement

### Code

```
int main() {
  int cnt = 5;
  while(cnt > 0) {
    printf("cnt = %d %s\n", --cnt, (cnt == 0) ? "cnt == 0" : "cnt != 0"); 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

### My Expected Output

```
cnt = 4 cnt != 0
cnt = 3 cnt != 0
cnt = 2 cnt != 0
cnt = 1 cnt != 0
cnt = 0 cnt == 0
```

### Real Output

```
cnt = 4 cnt != 0
cnt = 3 cnt != 0
cnt = 2 cnt != 0
cnt = 1 cnt != 0
cnt = 0 cnt != 0
```

I think when cnt = 1 after --cnt, cnt will have new value 0, and the test cnt == 0 will be true, but the real result isn't what I expect, why?

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is UB.. move the `--cnt` up above to a *statement by itself*.

Comment: I am not sure if this is UB. The order of evaluation of function parameters is unspecified by the standard. In this case, the last parameter of `printf` is evaluated before the preceding one. However, all expressions are evaluated to well defined results.

Comment: @Marian: Suppose you had instead `M(--p, p == q ? x : y)` where `p` and `q` are pointers; is it now the case that all expressions have well-defined results?